# PresentViewController completion block called too soon

Tags: ios, callback, viewcontroller

I am modally presenting a ViewController from another one. The completion block is being called immediately, while the presented VC is still presented. Why would that be? Code follows.

```
UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:...];
UINavigationController* nc = [sb instantiateViewController...];
nc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:nc
                   animated:YES
                 completion:^{ /* Called immediately! */ }];
```

There is stuff I want to do only when the presented VC is *finished*. I have a workaround but my understanding is I should be able to do it in the completion block.

Comment: Are you doing this on the main thread?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. `completion` is a block that fires when the animation block for presenting the view controller completes. It has nothing to do with the removal of the view controller.

Comment: By finished, do you mean when the animation presenting the VC has completed? Or when dismissing the VC?

Comment: I meant the second, but what happens is the first. I claim I was justified (see my answer); now I am enlightened.

Answer (score 0):

The completion block is called once the viewController has been presented, as per Apple's documentation. This is the intended behavior: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:

I'd suggest wiring up some sort of callback in your viewController's viewWillDissappear to perform an action if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

OK I had RTFM and saw this: "completion: The block to execute after the presentation finishes." Which *really does* imply what I thought. Ambiguous at best.

HOWEVER... elsewhere we read "The completion handler is called after the viewDidAppear: method is called on the presented view controller." Which is quite another thing, and confirms Ian.

So my workaround is actually the right way to do it...